# Odoo 10 : Using widgets to show number of survey

Tags: python, xml, button, widget, odoo

I created a  Survey button in customer form view which opens up the view containing all the surveys assigned to that customer. Below is the screenshot:

[image]

Now I want to show the number of surveys assigned to that customer in this form view itself. Just like there are numbers of meetings , opportunities ,sales,issues, tasks. I know they are using widget to get those numbers somehow. But i couldnt figure out how those widgets are bringing these numbers in form view. Can someone please guide me?

Below is the code of my Survey button :

```
<xpath expr='//div[@class="oe_button_box"]//button[@name="toggle_active"]' position='after'>   
    <button type="object" name="callSurvey" string="Survey" icon="survey.png" class="oe_stat_button"/>                   
</xpath>
```

Answer (score 0):

Achieved by defining a new field in model and computing that field with function :

```
survey_count = fields.Integer(string="Survey", compute='compute_survey_count')
```

The function :

```
@api.multi
def compute_survey_count(self):
    for partner in self:
            partner.survey_count = self.env['survey.user_input'].search_count([('email', '=', partner.email)])
```

The button in views.xml :

```
<xpath expr='//div[@class="oe_button_box"]//button[@name="toggle_active"]' position='after'>   
                <button type="object" name="callSurvey" icon="contacts_custom/static/description/survey.png" class="oe_stat_button">
                <field string="Surveys"  name="survey_count" widget="statinfo" modifiers="{'readonly': true}"/>
                </button>                   
            </xpath>
```